# Filename completion without suffix

Tags: autocompletion

By using `suffixesadd` I can navigate modules without file extensions. However, when I import modules by using path completion(`<C-X><C-F>`) the file extensions do not get omitted. Are there any options that make path completion omits specific suffixes?

Comment: What do you mean with "import modules by using path completion"? Which commands do you issue? Is this a feature from some plugin?

Comment: The built-in <C-X><C-F>. I use it to import modules from the file system.

Comment: Ah, so that's just filename completion then